# Why Java replaceAll() using regular expression need to add "\\" at front?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

For input String id, I want to do 4 steps like below :

1. Remove all not lowercase alphabet, number, "-", "_", "."
2. If "." is multiple and continuous, replace it to single "." (ex: he......llo -> he.llo)
3. If String start with ".", remove it.
4. If String ends with ".", remove it.

And Here is 4 Line of my code :

```
id = id.replaceAll("[^" + "a-z" + "0-9" + "-" + "_" + "." + "]", "");
id = id.replaceAll(".{2,}",".");
id = id.replaceAll("^.","");
id = id.replaceAll(".$","");
```

I found the return of rule 2 will be "." (ex : he...llo -> .)
and rule 3,4 will remove string which is not "."

So I fix the code like :

```
id = id.replaceAll("[^" + "a-z" + "0-9" + "-" + "_" + "." + "]", "");
id = id.replaceAll("\\.{2,}",".");
id = id.replaceAll("\\^.","");
id = id.replaceAll("\\.$","");
```

And it works fine.
I just don't understand. Is that regular expression need to add "\" twice before it uses?
If it is right, why rule 1 work just fine? Who can get me right answer specifically?
at last, I wonder can I code rule 3 and rule 4 at once? like using && to ?

Comment: `.` has special meaning in the context of regex. Thus if we want to match the literal dot, we have to escape it. A single backslash is not sufficient since this is the escape character for java-strings, and we need a literal backslash in the regex-`String`, which we get by using `\\`. Same goes for `^` and `$`. --- A remark: I imagine `id = id.replaceAll("\\^.","");` should be `id = id.replaceAll("^\\.","");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `.` in a regular expression means "match any single character"
- `\.` in a regular expression means "match a single dot/period/full-stop character". A different way to write this would be `[.]`, which has the same end result, but is semantically different (I'm not sure if this has a negative impact on the generated code to match the expression)
- `[abc.]` in a regular expression means "match a single character that must be 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or '.'" (`[^…]` inverts the meaning: match any character that is **not**). Attention: `-` has special meaning in a character class, so make sure you always put it first or last if you want to match the hyphen character specfically.

As for why the backslash has to be duplicated: Java itself uses the backslash to escape characters in a string. To get a literal backslash as part of the string, you have to escape the backslash itself: `"\\"` is a string containing a single backslash character (`"\"` is a syntax error in Java, because the backslash escapes the following quotation mark, i.e. the string is never terminated).

To reduce your logic down to two `replaceAll` calls, I would suggest to change the order of your calls and then join your expressions as alternatives with the `|` operator:

```
id = id.replaceAll(".+", ".") // fold all dots
        .replaceAll("[^a-z0-9_.-]|^\\.|\\.$", "");
```